# How do I dynamically alter javascript code

Tags: javascript

I am using a library that runs the following when it loads:

`init_function({...})`

I would like to modify the argument before passing it, e.g.

```
arg = {...}
arg['new key'] = 1

init_function(arg);
```

I can't make any changes to the library code.

Is it possible to access and modify the parameter to init_function?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? Why can't you change the library code?

Comment: I get an html page which is generated by a web service that I have no control over. The page uses a javascript library that I can't change and runs initiation code, e.g.


```
<html>
...
   <script src="third-party-library.js"></script>
...
   <script>
       init_function({...})     // init_function is defined in third-party-library.js
   </script>
</html>
```

I want to change the way that the javascript works by manipulating the object passed to init_function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function init_function(args) {
 console.log(args);
}

const old_init_function = init_function;

init_function = function(args) {
 args['new key'] = 1;
 return old_init_function.call(null, args);
}

init_function({});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to directly modify some library, but what you can do is
1. hijack in to the library loading process (if you are using a `<script>` tag, great; if you are using some build tool, possibly load the lib yourself?)
2. modify the source code
3. resume the loading process

Although a more prefered way to do it is just make a copy of the library, and make modification to directly.